# How to get the time of a process created remotely via ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh

I am currently writing a script whose purpose is to kill a process whose running time exceeds a threshold.  The "killer" is run on a bunch of hosts and the jobs are send by a server to each host.  My idea was to use 'ps' to get the running time of the job but all it prints is

17433 17433 ?   00:00:00 python

whatever the time I wait.

I tried to find a simplified example to avoid posting all the code I wrote.  Let's call S the server and H the host.

If I do the following steps:

1) ssh login@H from the server
2) python myscript.py (now logged on the host)
3) ps -U login (still on the host)

I get the same result than the one above 00:00:00 as far as the time is concerned.

How can I get the real execution time ?  When I do everything locally on my machine, it works fine.

I thank you very much for your help.

V.

Comment: Can you run each process with ulimit? Then they'll just die if the threshold is crossed. No need to kill them.

Comment: @lhf I think ulimit can only limit the CPU time, not the total elapsed time since the process started.

Comment: @chown, I interpreted "running time" as CPU time...

Comment: @lhf Oh, yea he did say running time huh, you might be right then.  V Lib, can you toss out some comments, replies, edits, or accept an answer?  Im curious to know if/how this got resolved, its an interesting idea.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can look at the creation of the pid file in /var/run, assuming your process created one and use the find command to see if it exceeds a certain threshold:

```
find /var/run/ -name "myProcess.pid" -mtime +1d
```

This will return the filename if it meets the criteria (last modified at least 1 day ago). You probably also want to check to make sure the process is actually running as it may have crashed and left the pid behind.

Comment: +1 This was going to be the exact info in the next edit of my answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
ps kstart_time -ef | grep myProc.py | awk '{print $5}'
```

This will show the start date/time of the proccess `myProc.py`:

```
[ 19:27 root@host ~ ]# ps kstart_time -ef | grep "httpd\|STIME" | awk '{print $5}'
STIME
19:25
```

---

Another option is `etime`.

`etime` is the elapsed time since the process was started, in the form `dd-hh:mm:ss`. dd is the number of days; hh, the number of hours; mm, the number of minutes; ss, the number of seconds.

```
[ 19:47 root@host ~ ]# ps -eo cmd,etime
CMD        ELAPSED
/bin/sh    2-16:04:45
```

---

And yet another way to do this:

Get the process pid and read off the timestamp in the corresponding subdirectory in `/proc`.

First, get the process pid using the ps command (`ps -ef` or `ps aux`)

Then, use the `ls` command to display the creation timestamp of the directory.

```
[ 19:57 root@host ~ ]# ls -ld /proc/1218
dr-xr-xr-x 5 jon jon 0 Sep 20 16:14 /proc/1218
```

You can tell from the timestamp that the process 1218 began executing on Sept 20, 16:14.

Comment: Thank you all guys for your answers !
I used Manny D solution, worked fine !

Answer (score 1):

If you want how long the process has been alive, you could try

```
stat -c %Y /proc/`pgrep python`
```

..which will give it back to you in epoch time.  If alternately you want the kill in one go, I suggest using the find mentioned above (but perhaps point it at `/proc`)